# WP - URL rewrite - custom post type/parent conflict

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I've been having trouble with this for a day now and can't seem to find a solution (it's probably blatantly obvious I just can't find/see it).

I have a **custom post type** called *product* where:

`'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product' )`

So the posts that I create for that post type have the URLs:

- *example.com/product/first-product*
- *example.com/product/second-product*
- *example.com/product/third-product*

etc..

I've also got a **page** created called *Product Info* that has the URL:

- *example.com/product*

I'd like to create a **page** that has *Product Info* as its parent and therefore has the URL *example.com/product/newpage*

For me this returns a 404 page not found, I'm guessing this is because WordPress rewrites the URL and checks the *product* post type for *newpage* and cannot find it.

How do you do this without WordPress giving a 404 Page Not Found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a conflict of slugs.

You will get conflicts if you have the same slug for a page and a CPT that uses that too. So for you, your CPT is using '`product`', and your page is too. That's conflicting and causing the 404.

Rename your page `Product Info` page' slug to `product-info`.

[image]

For safety purposes flush your permalink cache by setting them to Default, saving, then saving them as what you had previously.